# "do you think they will ... " vs "do you think if they will ..."

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am still not fully clear on whether to use 
*"do you think they will ... "*  or *"do you think if they will ..."*

E.g. 
*"do you think they will be interested in this"*
or 
*"do you think if they will be interested in this"*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use if to introduce reported yes-no questions and questions with or.

> Do you like me?(direct question)
>
> I asked if he liked me.(indirect question)

Do you think they will be interested in this? 

Is a direct question and you must use the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I say:

> do you think they will ...

You don't need an extra "if"

In your example:

> do you think they will be interested in this

Would be correct, otherwise it sounds strange, you have to many extra words.